# How do you use WinCrypt to exchange symmetric keys using RSA between client / server?

Tags: winapi, public-key-encryption, wincrypt

I'm completely lost looking at the WinCrypt samples, I think it's doing a lot of stuff automatically, but I don't get it.   I can use it fine locally but what I want to do is generate a RSA private/public key pair on two different networked systems.   From there one of them needs to export their public key to a buffer that I send over to the other system.   The receiving system would use that to use RSA encryption to encrypt the symmetric key that will be used and sent back to the other system.  Then both sides will have the symmetric key for data that will be sent encrypted back and forth using AES.

But I'm lost on how I tell it to use the remote public key received to encrypt (I wouldn't want to replace the public key on my generated private/public key).

Can someone help out listing the steps (with comments) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Use CNG. Plenty of samples.

Comment: I need to support older Windows OSes.  I migrated to new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68416913/why-does-cryptdecrpyt-from-ms-cryptoapi-not-decrypt-the-first-16-bytes-correct